# When to use "-ing"?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-usage, infinitive-vs-gerund

I'm preparing an answer to an email and struggle with this phrase:

> I appreciate the opportunity **to join** your team

It sounds correct to me, but I've got the feeling that this might be even better:

> I appreciate the opportunity **of joining** your team

Which one is the better / correct one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have the opportunity to do something (to-infinitive after opportunity).

We have the opportunity of doing something (-ing form after opportunity of)

We can use either to-infinitive or -ing form of the verb, without any difference in meaning. So both the sentences presented are grammatically correct and natural.

Comment: The first sentence sounds more natural to me.

Comment: By the way, I am not a sir :-)

Comment: In "the opportunity of doing sth" doing is a gerund. After a preposition follows a gerund, not a participle.